# Why is static routing failing in this case?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, pfsense

I am experimenting with networking and trying to get the following to work. `Computer A` has two interfaces, one connected to `Computer B` and the other connected to a pfSense router. I'd like to configure `Computer A` to act as a router.

`Computer B` has a ethernet interface (eth0) configured with an IP address 192.168.77.1/32. Then I added a default route:

```
ip route add default dev eth0
```

`Computer B` is plugged into eth1 of `Computer A`. This interface does not have an IP address assigned. I enable IP forwarding and add a route:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ip route add 192.168.77.1/32 dev eth1
```

On the pfSense router I add a firewall rule to allow traffic with `source: 192.168.77.0/24, destination: any`. I then add a route:

```
route add 192.168.77.0/24 10.0.0.2
```

[image]

In my mind, I thought this should work. Observations:

1. `Computer A` can ping `Computer B` at 192.168.77.1
2. `Computer B` can ping `Computer A` at 10.0.0.2
3. `Computer B` can *not* ping anything on the Internet
4. `Computer B` can *not* ping pfSense at 10.0.0.1
5. pfSense can *not* ping `Computer B` at 192.168.77.1

Additional info:

Routing table for `Computer B`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Routing table for `Computer A`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.77.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1
```

Routing table of pfSense:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    UGS      vtnet0
10.0.0.0/24        link#2             U        vtnet1
10.0.0.1           link#2             UHS         lo0
192.168.77.0/24    10.0.0.2           UGS      vtnet1
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/20 link#1             U        vtnet0
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    link#1             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#4             UH          lo0
```

Comment: What routes does Computer A have? And once again, have you used a packet capture tool to check how far the packets go? Do the ping requests reach Computer B (if they enter one interface, do they exit another), do they reach the pfSense router, do the responses reach Computer B again?

Comment: @user1686 Updated question with additional info.

Comment: Observation #2 is misleading because, under Linux, the IP address actually belongs to the host even though you use commands to "assign" the IP address to an interface.  So #2 simply means that B can ping A, and implies nothing about any routing within A or accessing a specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try:

> Computer B is plugged into eth1 of Computer A. This interface does not have an IP address assigned.

Usually you assign an IP address to this interface (e.g. 192.168.77.2/24), and you also make sure eth0 on Computer A has a proper subnet, e.g. 192.168.77.1/24.

Even though there are just two computers in the subnet, it's still a subnet.

It actually might work in your unusual setup (or a variation), but since it's not working, try the usual setup first.

Comment: I'm actually specifically trying to get away with not having extra IPs assigned to Computer A. I've seen this sort of /32 subnet work with computers connected via RS232 and SLIP protocol.

Comment: I think SLIP is a special case; the successor PPP already requires two IP addresses, IIRC. Still: (1) if you try it that way, then you know if this was the problem, or if the problem lies elsewhere; (2) now the question is **why** you want to avoid an extra IP - perhaps one can achieve this in a different way.

Comment: Well, I'm not necessarily trying to accomplish any practical goal here, just understand. The idea came from thinking about how ISPs may want to conserve global IP addresses. It seems awfully wasteful to create a /31 subnet for every single customer, effectively wasting half of the limited number of IP that exist.

Comment: ISPs use [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), which has nothing to do with your scenario. ISP customers have a home router which typically NATs the single private IP they get from their ISP to a complete /24 subnet with routing (and **with** an address to the equivalent of your `eth1`). Again, this has nothing to do with your scenario. And this is very different from how it worked 30 years ago with SLIP and dialup. (Also, it really helps if you put this background information in your question).